# How to create a POJO for the following json?

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I want to map following json to a pojo using jackson.

```
{
  "colors": {
    "red": {
      "colorCode": "#FF0000"
    },
    "green": {
      "colorCode": "#00FF00"
    },
    "blue": {
      "colorCode": "#0000FF"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any possible way to create a single POJO without having to create POJOs for each color because every color contains same parameter(colorCode)?

Note: I tried using @jsonAlias but it wont work because it overwrites that parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use a Map < String, Color > (or maybe Enum if you have a fixed list of colors)

```
public class Color{
  private String colorCode;

  //constructor, getter, setter
} 
public class Pojo{
   private Map<String,Color> colors;

  //constructor, getter, setter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the color is just the name. Unless blue Behaves differently then Red, then they should not be separate classes.

```
Public class Color{
Private string colorCode;
Private string title

Color(string colorCode, string title){
This.colorCode =colorCode;
This.title = title;
}
```

Getter setters etc